# Pega primeiro registro SQL Bullider Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Não estou conseguindo pegar o primeiro registro sem usar foreach

```
query = "SELECT *, (SELECT count(*) FROM corridas c WHERE c.motoqueiro = u.id AND (c.status = 0 OR c.status = 1)) as corrida ,distance_between(u.latitude, u.longitude, $lat, $lon) as km FROM (SELECT * FROM motoqueiros WHERE DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 8 SECOND) <= data_update) order by km ASC LIMIT 1";

    $data = DB::select($query);
```

> $data[0], erro > Undefined offset: 0
>
> toArray, erro > Fatal error: Call to a member function toArray() on array
>
> .get , erro > Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on array

Já tentei usar $data[0], toArray, .get, first e nada, alguém me ajuda ae, vlw!

Comment: O erro não esta nesta parte do código. Copiei todo o código. Alias, leia o erro com atenção "Fatal error: Call to a member function toArray() on array"

Comment: Provavelmente sua query está errada e $data está recebendo um false. Tente fazer um `var_dump($data)` e confirme a estrutura.